# SSIS and Oracle Error code: 0x80040E4D

Tags: oracle, ssis

I always get this error: 0x80040E4D. Invalid username/password; logon denied.
I've set the username and password in the package with EncryptSensitiveWithPassword protection level.
I've tried to put the package into the SSIS package store and I've created a config file, but all was useless.

I should have a bit of help, please.

Comment: Can you connect to your database via SQL*Plus (SQL command line) with the user and password which is being refused elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks for response, otherwise yes, I can. I can run the package in the VS 2010, but when I want to run the package in the SQL Manager, it try to run under my username not under the user what I set in the package.

Answer (score 0):

EncryptSensitiveWithPassword is a option to save the package's encrypted data (like the oracle's user name and password) so If someone tries to execute the package without providing the password, package execution fails.

I think you have issues on your config file, maybe the information sensitive information is not being loaded from it.

Comment: Hi. There were two problems. 1. It works only with a 32bit Oracle client for me. 2. I was the package owner (as an AD user), but the service was running under the name NetworkService so it couldn't check my user.